# Android ListFragment vs ListActivity getCount() method

Tags: android, listactivity, android-listfragment

In my Android app, I created a `ListFragment` which gets added to an `Activity` that extends `FragmentActivity`. From within that ListFragment, I set an `Adapter`. The layout which I have chosen is an extremely simple and bare-bones layout which only consists of a single TextView. The data being passed to the Adapter

Everything works fine. The data is being displayed perfectly fine and everything looks as expected.

The **problem** however is that the `getCount()` method within the adapter gets fired infinitely and never stops. When I saw this behaviour, I then swapped out the `ListFragment` and replaced it with a `ListActivity`. I then start this Activity and then set the Adapter just as I did with the `ListFragment`. Surprisingly, the `getCount()` method now doesn't fire infinitely amount of times.

Is there an underlying reason why the getCount() infinitely fires within a `Fragment` and not in a `ListActivity`?

Fragment Transaction:

```
FragmentTransaction ft    = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.add(R.id.fragment, offerFragment);
ft.show(offerFragment);
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

ListActivity Start:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, PlusOfferListActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Single Row Layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@color/cell">

        <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/titleTextView"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what is the implementation of getCount method?

Comment: @Rafik991 `return listData.size();`